# Ruby Enterprise Edition gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/zones.rb:56: [BUG] Segmentation fault

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to run my rails application with Ruby Enterprise Edition but I'm getting following error:

```
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/
activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/
time/zones.rb:56: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [i686-linux], MBARI 0x8770, 
Ruby Enterprise Edition 2011.03
```

Any idea what could be wrong? I tried building REE with GCC 4.4.1 and 4.4.2 and in both cases I'm getting error.

The thing is that my application uses threads and nokogiri.

How can I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

First try to see if you can reproduce the problem with a REE installation without using RVM. If you don't see segfault when using custom compiled REE (without RVM), then most likely your RVM installation is hosed. After that, try updating RVM and doing clean reinstall of REE and that should solve your problem.

There have been few bugs in RVM which can cause use of native gems which weren't compiled with current version of Ruby.